# Latex Error: Command crashed: biber.exe

Tags: biblatex, miktex, texstudio, biber

I am getting an error when running Bibliography on Windows 10, using MikTex 2.9 and TexStudio 2.10, running biblatex 3.1 and biber 2.2, all 64 bit.

```
Process started: biber.exe "MWE"
Error: Command crashed: biber.exe "MWE"
Process exited with error(s)
```

In the log file are the following errors:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'MWE.bbl' not found.
No file MWE.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 10.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 10.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'john' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 12.
```

I am running the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
    @book{john,
        author  = {John Johnson},
        title   = {Booktitle},
        year    = {2016}
        }
    \end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
    Hello\cite{john}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I also tried running from the command line:

```
biber --tool MWE.bib
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
The procedure entry point Perl_gv_fetchpv could not be located in the dynamic link library
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-726f676965\cache-19a661c7206c3f168e864t6as864\biber.exe
```

Removing the par-726f676965 folder doesn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did it start crashing suddenly? Sometimes it does that and I always reinstall. I wish to know why too.

Comment: You could get biber from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/2.3/binaries/Windows/ and check if this crash too (either replace the miktex biber or put the biber.exe somewhere in the path where it is found first, or rename the biber.exe to e.g. bibernew.exe and use this). If it crashes too you know that it is not miktex and you can make a bug report on the biber site.

Comment: @percusse Yes, it did crash suddenly. A complete MikTex reinstall was indeed the solution.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was trying a reinstall. Therefore I was not able to try your solution. Fortunately the reinstall worked.

Comment: I;m having the same problem here, reinstalled TexLive on windows 10, still got the error. The sourceforge page has no forum or bugs reported, seems like they moved to GiHub (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues)... I will google more and try other stuff before reporting.

Comment: Update: After adding the updated biber.exe file and still get the error I decided to... reboot, something as simple as that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete reinstall of MikTex was the solution for me. See also comments to the opening post.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the used filename for your bib file from `\bibliography.bib` to `bibliography.bib`.  The `\` starts a command `\bibliography` causing your error.

The following MWE compiles with no errors with my current miktex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib} % <================================
    @book{john,
        author  = {John Johnson},
        title   = {Booktitle},
        year    = {2016}
        }
    \end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}  % <================================

\begin{document}
    Hello \cite{john}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was unfortunately just part of the the solution. The error reported in the opening post kept appearing. I changed the Opening Post accordingly.